# EntityFramwowork 6 - Code first - TPT Inheritance - Different schema for base class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I've the following entity and DBContext in one assembly:

```
public class Notification
{
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Message { get; set; }
}

public class BaseModelContext : DbContext
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public BaseModelContext()
    {
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public BaseModelContext(string connectionString, ContextMode mode) : base(connectionString, mode)
    {
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public BaseModelContext(DbConnection connection, ContextMode mode) : base(connection, mode)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in another assembly I want to derive from the Notification entity:

```
public class TransportNotification : Notification
{
    public virtual int Position { get; set; }
}

public class TransportModelContext : MarvinDbContext
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public TransportModelContext()
    {
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public TransportModelContext(string connectionString, ContextMode mode) : base(connectionString, mode)
    {
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public TransportModelContext(DbConnection connection, ContextMode mode) : base(connection, mode)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TransportNotification>().ToTable("TransportNotifications");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Notification> TransportNotifications { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is that I have just one Notification table and one or more derivations of Notification in other tables with different DBContexts and schemas. Is this possible? And if so, does anyone how?
In my tests the Notification table was also created by the migration tool (add-migration).

Comment: Is there is specific reason why you have multiple contexts for entities you want to inherit?

Comment: Yes, my Notification entity is placed within a framework assembly and users can add their own Notification derivations in their own projects. So the Notification is placed in e.g SchemaA and the users places their derivation in CustomerSchemaA. That's the plan but I don't know if EF supports that.